# How can I politely ask a person to re-sign a document?

Tags: professionalism

How do I ask a person to re-sign a document because we've lost the first signed copy?

Comment: Is it possible that you could tell them that the document has been updated and you'll need them so sign a new one? (You run the risk here of them noticing the document looks the same)

Comment: Does the document contain personal/sensitive information?

Comment: This will greatly depend on the significance of the document.  Is it a simple  document like "I read the company handbook." or something more sophisticated....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just common sense.

Comment: @schizoid04: Lying to your employees is NEVER good policy.

Answer (score 17):

> Dear XYZ,
>   We have misplaced the document <A>. Could you kindly sign another copy of the document? We regret the inconvenience caused.
>   
>   Thanks& Regards, 
> Fayd

Answer (score 4):

I think being straightforward about this should be fine.

It's something that happens.

You **could** try to be sneaky about it with an excuse, but if it were me I'd just repeat your question above, less the first few words.

Communicate to the person, state the problem that has occurred briefly, and move on to the subject of when he can come in to re-sign.

"Hi [Name], Due to a clerical error, it seems we're going to need to ask you to re-sign this document. What times would you be available?"

This should keep his focus on what dates on his calendar are open while you're speaking with him, rather than what possible reasons he will be needing to re-sign. He'll probably think nothing of it afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

As long as there are no issues whatsoever attached to the date of his signature, your best bet is to come clean, admit that the firm lost or destroyed the original, and ask him to sign a copy.  Be prepared to explain, as best as you can, how the firm managed to lose or destroy the original, and what corrective action has been taken to ensure it doesn't happen again.

If there are issues attached to the date, you potentially have a major legal problem on your hands, and you definitely need corporate counsel involved immediately.  If, for example, the document is his agreement not to do something for some period of time after his signature, and the original was about to expire, the employee is unlikely to be happy with what he may perceive (potentially correctly!) as a ploy to extend the restriction.  Your misfeasance cannot be allowed to result in his injury.  You're going to have to find a way to let him sign a new, nonstandard document, that preserves the original deadlines.

My personal feeling is that you have far bigger problems on your hands than how to persuade the guy to re-sign the document.  How did you manage to lose something important enough to require his signature in the first place?